# Gray cone obscuring/clipping the 3D Viewport

Tags: 3d-view, objects

When looking at my objects in 3d view I'm seeing a gray cone that seems to be hiding other objects.

Can anyone help me turn this off and explain what it is please.

Screenshots attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a stray object. Mind uploading the .blend to PasteAll, http://www.pasteall.org/blend/, and posting it here?

Comment: Here you go http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32799

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You somehow enabled the clipping region (or clipping border). It's created in 2D, but projects into 3D, thus it looks like a cone from certain angles.

Disable it by clicking *View > View Region> Clipping Region...* in *3D View* header, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks CoDEmanX that did it. Think I'd been trying for select render border (Ctrl+B) and hit Clipping Border instead.

Comment: If you draw the border in a perspective view, it will actually be a cone.