# Why was the visibility of objects in 3d Viewport restricted to a cone form?

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools

I intended to select objects with "Selection group" tool, so in order to achieve that:

1. pressed <kbd>B</kbd> hotkey with <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> button;
2. moved mouse to form rectangular area.

As a result it removed everything what was outside of rectangular area, forming infinite rectangular pyramid with it's tip on the position of my viewport when I was looking from when making selection. I can rotate around that pyramid now, where only objects (their parts) fitting that rectangular area are visible.

How can I cancel it to see all my objects back? <kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18783/gray-cone-obscuring-clipping-the-3d-viewport. As I understand, you aren't sure which key you pressed ?

Comment: @MrZak yes, it's exactly the same what I've seen. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what was that, but I think I fixed it:

- View -> Toggle Quad View

  ... objects visibility was still restricted to lie within that pyramid, but it was visible from 4 different sides
- View -> Toggle Quad View (again)

  ... can see everything now

Comment: yeah, that fixed it for me. thanks