# Does some kind of "Box as view boundaries" exist?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, selection-tools

is there a function to "clip-view" everything that is (in the editor view) inside a certain box? Like, hide everything that is outside the box and clip objects that are crossing the surfaces of the box.

thanks!

Florian[image]

Comment: There is nothing exactly like that. You have the boolean modifier, camera clipping planes, z-pass for compositing and **holdout** material nodes.

Comment: Closest thing I can think of is [Clipping Border](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18783/gray-cone-obscuring-clipping-the-3d-viewport)