# Different viewports showing different things?

Tags: rendering, materials, 3d-view

When ever I switch the viewports, it shows different things. This only started after I scaled the uv maps. I never touched touched the actual objects itself. In the solid everything disappears except some cropped objects. In matpreview, everything is normal. In rendered, the bricks are scaled for some reason. If you have any ideas as to why this is happening, please tell me.([image]) Thank you so much![[image: First is the solid preview][1]][image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18783/gray-cone-obscuring-clipping-the-3d-viewport

Comment: That fixed the solid viewport problem. However, the bricks are still scaled in the rendered view. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please ask only one question per post, it gets confusing otherwise.