# I don't know why my 3D object has been cropped on default shading view (the right window), anyone can figure it out?

Tags: modeling

I don't know why my 3D object has been cropped on default shading view (the right window), I have a really strange thing happening right now - I'm sure there's a reason for it, I really want to figure out a way to fix it.

[image]

Comment: it's Clipping Border, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18783/gray-cone-obscuring-clipping-the-3d-viewport

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you accidentally enabled clipping region.
[image]

Also I can see your camera clipping start distance is set to 4.6 meters, and by the scale of things in your scene this distance seems too big.

You can change the camera clipping settings by going into the camera properties tab and checking the clip start distance.
[image]

Just so you know, if you want to change the viewport clipping (and is not in active camera view), go into the "view" tab and see if the clipping start distance is set to a high value. (the viewport clipping settings can be different than the camera clipping settings).

[image]

Comment: Thanks you Alexandre, I fixed the problem. I am a beginner on Blender, thanks for your recommendation ;)