# How to remove polygonal shadow in Blender?

Tags: shadows

I have tried hiding all objects in the scene but this shadow shape doesn't go away. Is it a world setting. It's my first time experiencing this. I have also search online and on Youtube but I haven't found any similar issue.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18783/gray-cone-obscuring-clipping-the-3d-viewport ?

Comment: if Gorgious comment didn't help, please provide blend file

Comment: Oh my goodness @Gorgious fixed it!!! Thank you!!!